# Disabling Update panel from content page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Hello I have a ToolkitScriptManager and update panel on master page. I want to disable update panel functionality on a content page but it should work fine for other pages.

```
Master Page Code:
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
    EnableScriptLocalization="true" ScriptMode="Release" CompositeScript-  
ScriptMode="Release" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpEmail" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphMain" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Content Page Code:(e.g. Page1.aspx)
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="Server">
Code Here
</asp:Content>
```

So Now I want to that Update panel functionality should not work on Page1.aspx but it should work on other content pages of same master page. Please help

Comment: Move your update panel inside the pages that you wish to use it, and delete it from the master page. Or create a second PlaceHolder for page1 that is outside updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

what about on the code behind to check for the name of the page and set the visibility of cphMain to false?  http://forums.asp.net/t/1163743.aspx

Have you explored Razor + MVC yet?

Comment: Have you explored Razor + MVC yet?--- No

Answer (score 0):

On the page where it should be disabled, try something like this:

```
UpdatePanel panel = Page.Form.FindControl("UpdatePanel1") as UpdatePanel;
if (panel != null)
{
    panel.Enabled = false;
}
```

Depending on where the UpdatePanel is located in the master page, you may need to search the page recursively, like this:

```
private void DisableControl(Control parentCtrl, string controlID)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parentCtrl.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == controlID)
        {
            ((WebControl)ctrl).Enabled = false;
            continue;
        }
        DisableControl(ctrl, controlID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either cast Master property on content page to correct masterpage type, or use

```
<%@ MasterType %>
```

to have typed master page.
Then you will have access to controls on it and can disable update panel.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way yet better than the below, To override the onInit and add that code

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        //disables the ajax effect, and allows postback
       ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).EnablePartialRendering = false;


        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```